# Cannot navigate Microsoft store after app install / update

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store

Every time i go to the store and install a new app or update an existing one, I go back to the main screen of Store after a few screen refreshes. And then oddly, scrolling doesn't work and neither do the buttons, although the Tiles are fine. I then have to close the app and then re-open it and things are back to normal.

I don't know if this is a weird bug or just the way it is. Could anyone please confirm and / or give a possible explanation?

Comment: How are you trying to scroll? By mouse wheel, by grabbing and dragging the scroll bar, or by touch (flick)?

Comment: @techie007 mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this as well (mouse wheel not working when returnging to main screan of the Store, and similar in some other apps as well).

What works for me is to click on a blank area of the background (for example above the scroll bar but below the tiles).  This ensures that the background is active (focused) and makes it start capturing the mouse wheel again.

IMO it's annoying, and hopfully they'll fix that. ;)